# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 (|a_n| + |b_n|)$ converges.

Tags: fourier-series

(Bartle's book; The elements of real analysis, 2nd edition, Exercise 38.u)

Suppose that $f$ and $f'$ are continuous with period $2\pi$ and that $f''$ is piecewise continuous with period $2\pi$. Show that the Fourier coefficients $a_n$, $b_n$ of $f$ are such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 (|a_n| + |b_n|)$ is convergent.

Comment: Are you sure you have read the exercise correctly?

Comment: It might be useful to note that if $f(2\pi)=f(0)$ and $f'(2\pi)=f'(0)$, then by integration by parts $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)e^{inx}\,dx=-\frac1{n^2}\int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)e^{inx}\,dx$$

Comment: NOT Exactly. In the book it is assumed that $f''$ is piecewise continuous. But it seems that "period $2\pi$ means $f(2\pi)=f(0)$ and $f'(2\pi)=f'(0)$.

Comment: Well, making the constraints on $f''$ weaker changes the problem in the wrong direction. Essentially, the version you wrote says that the series of Fourier coefficients of a continuous function converges absolutely. Which is wrong. Allowing piecewise continuous functions makes that claim not more true.

Comment: The problem is changed. Thank you for your comments.